# What is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{x+h} - e^x}{h}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the  $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{e^{x+h} - e^x}{h}$?

I'm not sure how to go about getting the solution.

Comment: May you assume knowledge of the derivative of $e^x$, i.e. do you know $\frac{d}{dx} e^x$? Then there is a quite simple answer.

Comment: Note that $e^{x+h} = e^x e^h$.

Comment: should I change it into inverse form to get the solution?

Comment: To @Eff 's point, this appears to be a "definition of the derivative" limit.

Comment: Hint: $e^h=1+h+h^2/2!+h^3/3!+\dots$

Comment: Use the limit definition of $e^x$ (not the Taylor series). It pops out quite easily if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $e = \lim_{x \to 0}(1 + x)^\frac{1}{x}$(this is a variation of the limit definition of $e$). Let $a = e^x - 1$ so that $\ln(a + 1) = x$. We can evaluate the limit using the property of logarithms.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} &= \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{a}{\ln(a + 1)}\\
&= \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}\ln(a + 1)}\\
&= \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{1}{\ln((1 + a)^\frac{1}{a})}\\
&= \frac{1}{\ln(\lim_{a \to 0}(1 + a)^\frac{1}{a})}\\
&= \frac{1}{\ln(e)} = 1
\end{align}
I like this method as it doesn't requires l'Hopital's rule. In order to use l'Hopitals rule you would need to know the derivative of $e^x$, but the limit you listed is often used in finding the derivative of $e^x$

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can look at this problem, both of them were hinted at in the comments section. If you look closely at your expression you will see that it is of the form:

$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

where in this case $f(x) = \exp(x)$. The expression above is of course the definition of the derivative of $f(x)$, which you should be able to easily find.

A more interesting way to look at this is to look at:

$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} e^x \frac{\left( e^h - 1 \right)}{h} = e^x \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\left( e^h - 1 \right)}{h} $$

both top and bottom of the fraction approach $0$. You may now apply Hopital's rule with respect to h, and evaluate the limit.

Comment: Do you think that Hopital's rule would be known to the OP?

Comment: That rule is not something that I have learned before. I'm coming from a grade 12 Calculus perspective. That's a bit too advance for me.

Comment: You are probably right, I think the most straight forward way is to use the definition of differentiation. The l'Hopital rule method just gives more insight in the actual behavior of the limit.

Comment: Stefano, by applying LHopital, you would assume that you already knew $\frac{d}{dx} e^x$.